# Octopus Deploy not running PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, octopus-deploy

I have a Process Step in Octopus Deploy to run some Selenium WebDriver tests by calling a PowerShell script but it results in an error.

The PowerShell script is as follows:

```
set nunitPath="C:\AutomatedTests"
cd %nunitPath%\
nunit-console SiteCore.nunit /include:BulkyWasteTests
```

When the deployment takes place and the Process Step to run the script takes place, the following error occurs:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'C:\Octopus\Work\20170110115049-7\%nunitPath%\' because it does not exist.

At C:\Octopus\Work\20170110115049-7\Script.ps1:2 char:3

+ cd %nunitPath%\

+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Octopus\Work...-7\%nunitPath %\:String) [Set-Location],    ItemNotFoundException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :     PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

The remote script failed with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why the error is reporting a different location to the location specified in the PowerShell script.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

cd is an alias for Set-Location, so you can tell that it's the second line you need to change by looking at the error.  Your cd line is trying to set the location to the %nunitpath% environment variable rather than the nunitPath script variable.

To reference the script variable use $nunitpath

So your script should look like:

```
set nunitPath "C:\AutomatedTests"
cd $nunitpath
nunit-console SiteCore.nunit /include:BulkyWasteTests
```

Edited with @4c74356b41 additional correct comment.

Comment: set doesn't work that way in powershell, as it is an alias to set-variable, should be `set nunitPath "C:\AutomatedTests"`

Comment: I changed the syntax of the script so that it is correct but I still get the same error.  Perhaps it is a permission problem on the server?

Comment: You should at least be getting a different error can you post that?

Comment: I solved the latest error, which was :
ObjectNotFound: (nunit-console:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException 
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: However, I am now getting another error:
 OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:53393/session. 
 The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell doesn't use `%variablename%` syntax for expanding environment variable references in a string. That's cmd.exe syntax. In PowerShell, write `$env:variablename` instead.